# Need steps to configure Oracle Cloud Infrastructure on Jenkins agent

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oracle-cloud-infrastructure-classic

> Need steps to configure OCI on Jenkins agent.

Comment: Please elaborate more ?

Comment: > On the OCI VM created through OCI console, i need to install Jenkins master node and need to add jenkins slave nodes. I need the detailed steps of installation and configuration. Pls help.

Comment: @SantoshJoshi, any update on this?

Answer (score 0):

i hope this Answer Helps you. 
 After Configuring your oci VM and installing your jenkins
now you need to create your agent. 
**Steps after configuring jenkins on your VM :**

- Go ManageJenkins > Plugins > Available Plugins > Search for Oracle Cloud Infrastructure Compute Plugin  click install and Restart Jenkins
- After Installing the plugin you will need to setup your OCI by navigating to the Jenkins Server console, click Manage Jenkins, then Manage Nodes and Clouds, and Configure Clouds. Click Add a new cloud and select Oracle Cloud Infrastructure Compute. In Credentials, click Add. you will need to provide your configurations such as Tennantid ocid fingerprint etc .. (if you didnt configure oci setup you can check oci configurations documentation :https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/API/Concepts/apisigningkey.htm). 
  You also need to provide policies if you're not an admin in your Tenancy
- After providing your configurations click Verfiy Credentials and check if you can connect successfully to your OCI.
- You will need to add a template on your oci cloud plugin check the plugin documentation for more details for each input https://plugins.jenkins.io/oracle-cloud-infrastructure-compute/#plugin-content-add-oci-template  **dont forget to save and apply**
- To test Your agent now Go to Manage Jenkins > Nodes you will find Provision  via oracle cloud infrastructure instance like that : [image]  Click on "agent name" in that picture ci agent and Enter a number of nodes that should be provisioned like this : [image]
  You will see your oracle instance Provisiond and you can call through your jenkins file as agent and work with. 
   
  I hope this answer can help you to provision Jenkins agent using oci.